# How to request AudioFocus for android devices above api level 20?

Tags: android, android-tv, android-audiomanager

I implemented the call using AudioManager class as mention in this doc : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus. I can see the audio manager resource get held when I call :

```
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

but audio manager resource doesn't get released by calling :

```
audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener);
```

Also, as mentioned in the document shared above:

> For apps that target Android 5.0 (API level 21) and later, audio apps
>   should use AudioAttributes to describe the type of audio your app is
>   playing. For example, apps that play speech should specify
>   CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH.

But in AudioManager class function to call with AudioAttributes is marked as SystemApi mentioned below:

```
@SystemApi
    @RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)
    public int requestAudioFocus(OnAudioFocusChangeListener l,
            @NonNull AudioAttributes requestAttributes,
            int durationHint,
            int flags)
```

So, which function should be called for devices between api level 20 (Android L) & 26 (Android O) to requestAudioFocus() and AbandonAudioFocus() ?

Answer (score 1):

> audio manager resource doesn't get released

What does that mean? How can you tell?

a) If you request `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` and then abandon it, then there will be silence.

For example, I'm listening to music from app A, then I start listening to music from app B and pause it. App A won't automatically start playing and that's fine. That's the difference from transient focus.

> - Request permanent audio focus (`AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN`) when you plan to play audio for the foreseeable future (for example, when playing music) and you expect the previous holder of audio focus to stop playing.

b) You're responsible for stopping playback when you abandon focus.

If you abandon focus and keep playing, you're no longer participating in audio focus mechanism. If I started another music player other than your app the system wouldn't be able to stop your app's playback, when my other music player requested audio focus.

> When you finish playback, call `abandonAudioFocus()`.

Source: [Audio focus pre-Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#audio_focus_pre-android_80)

---

> which function should be called for devices [L-O]

The only one available with one of the `AudioManager.STREAM_*` constants as mentioned in [Audio focus pre-Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#audio_focus_pre-android_80).

```
// Request audio focus for playback
val result: Int = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
    afChangeListener,
    // Use the music stream.
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, // There's no AudioAttributes, just the more general constant.
    // Request permanent focus.
    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
)
```

---

> For apps that target Android 5.0 (API level 21) and later, audio apps should use `AudioAttributes` to describe the type of audio your app is playing.

The quote you mentioned is not about the `requestAudioFocus` call, it's about `setAudioAttributes`, which is available on `MediaPlayer`, `SoundPool.Builder`, and all the other things that play sound.

Comment: Consider using [`AudioManagerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/AudioManagerCompat).

Comment: so,
 public int requestAudioFocus(OnAudioFocusChangeListener l, int streamType, int durationHint) {}
function is deprecated. And eventually we have to use : public int requestAudioFocus(@NonNull AudioFocusRequest focusRequest) {}

Comment: One method is deprecated but it's the only method until api 26. If you don't want to deal with the differences use AudioManagerCompat, which provides an api similar to the new AudioFocusRequest for all platforms.

Comment: AudioManagerCompat is androidX component and I don't use androidx right now for my project.

Comment: In that case it's an if-else for you. Deprecated doesn't mean to never use it. It was perfectly valid at the time it came out and it's valid if you don't use AndroidX. So on api 21-25 use the deprecated method and from api 26 onwards use the new method. It's alright.